# Wrapping text in UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uitextview

UPDATE: Looks like the `UITextView`'s width is bigger than screen's width.

It is strange since I created the `UITextView` using a storyboard and in preview mode it looks like it's width is less than that of the `UIViewController`.

I have a `UITextView`, in a `UIViewController`, that was created using storyboard.

I have similar code to populate the text in the `UITextView`.

```c
self.taskGroupDescriptionTextView.text = taskGroup.description
self.taskGroupDescriptionTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByCharWrapping
```

I tried different types of `lineBreakMode`, break by char/word. None of them work.

My `UIViewController` when run on iOS simulator still has text that extends beyond the screen.

Comment: How are your constraints set up?

Comment: I added a gray background to UITextView and it looks like width is not constrained to screen width. Width of UITextView is more than width of screen. How do I make sure width of UITextView is only as big as container

Comment: did you try to change the line number of your textview?

Answer (score 2):

You should set constraints. Here's an example how to do it:

[image]

You click on your UITextView so that you can start editing it. At the bottom of the storyboard there are few icons and clicking on the one shown in the image will open up an editor where you can add constraints. You have plenty of options (pin to left, right, top, bottom, fix height or width, aspect ratio,... and even more if you click on a neighbour icon). Keep in mind that you have to set enough constraint so that it will be reasonable for your view controller to calculate the frame size of your view. But no worries, if you'll forget something you'll get an error.